# One-hot encode sentence using list of vocabulary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I need to create a function that takes a list of strings as the input and each string is a string of the contents of a book. The output needs to be a 2D np array of counts where the rows are the books from the input string and the columns are the counts for all the words in the "global vocabulary". So if two strings are the input and they have 50 unique words the shape of the matrix would be (2,50).

I have a previous code that takes a list of strings and creates a dictionary out of the unique words of the strings in lexicographer order named vocabulary that I am allowed to use, I just can't figure out how to turn this dictionary into a matrix.

Here's what I have so far but it's not working because "list indices must be integers or slices not str":

```
def feature(strings):

    import numpy as np

    array_dict = global_vocab(strings)
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(strings)):
        names = strings[i]
        matrix = np.array([array_dict[i] for i in names])
    
    print (matrix)
```

So if the input it
["This is string one", "This is string two"]
the function should return the array

```
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0 1
```

I also have these previous codes that I am using:

```
def word_count(book):

    try:
        from collections import defaultdict
    
        file = book.lower().split()
        my_dict = defaultdict(int)
        for item in file:
            if len(item)>2:
                my_dict[item] += 1
            
        return my_dict
    
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None

def global_vocab(strings):

    from collections import defaultdict

    my_dict = []
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(strings)):
        words = strings[i]
        sentences = word_count(words)
        my_dict.extend(sentences)

    return sorted(my_dict)
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your input, and an example of what the output should look like?

Comment: you don't need to do i = 0

Comment: what type of data does your global_vocabulary return? maybe you should try it like array_dict = [*global_vocabulary(strings)] or get rid of the brackets

Comment: @MattHowell I added what the input and output will look like

Comment: @Kaiyaha global_vocabulary returns a dictionary of all the unique words found in the strings, I don't need to include this function I just thought it would simplify the process

Comment: Why is your output shaped `(2, 5)`? Aren't there only 4 words in the input?

Comment: @cluelesscoder get rid of the brackets, now you have a list with one element which is your dictionary, you cannot access your dictionary values now

Comment: @Kaiyaha I'm still getting the error that "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" even after taking out the brackets

Comment: @MateenUlhaq The words "one" and "two" are considered unique so the array has to include a space for both of them

Comment: @cluelesscoder well can you show your global_vocabulary as well? looks like it returns a list, not a dictionary

Comment: @cluelesscoder How do you expect this to be a dictionary when you specified it as a list? :)

Comment: @Kaiyaha haha sorry I'm really new at this I still don't understand what makes them different

Comment: @cluelesscoder a dictionary is a structure like {'key_1': value_1, 'key_2': value_2 ...}. Dictionary allowes you to access the value by its key like dict['key_1'] = value_1

Answer (score 0):

First, process your strings into lists of words:

```
wordss = [s.split() for s in strings]
```

If you have a dictionary, you can map these to some ordinal numbers. Here, I've just constructed my own dictionary instead:

```
unique_words = set(word for words in wordss for word in words)
dictionary = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(unique_words)}
```

> Note: If you'd prefer a "nicer" ordering, you can use this instead:
>
> ```
> unique_words = {word: 0 for words in wordss for word in words}
> dictionary = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(unique_words)}
> ```

Finally, the one-hot encoding:

```
idxss = [[dictionary[word] for word in words] for words in wordss]
embedding = np.zeros((len(idxss), len(dictionary)), dtype=np.uint8)

for i, idxs in enumerate(idxss):
    embedding[i, idxs] = 1
```

---

**Full example:**

```
def embed(strings, dictionary=None):
    wordss = [s.split() for s in strings]
    
    if dictionary is None:
        unique_words = {word: 0 for words in wordss for word in words}
        dictionary = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(unique_words)}
    
    idxss = [[dictionary[word] for word in words] for words in wordss]
    embedding = np.zeros((len(idxss), len(dictionary)), dtype=np.uint8)

    for i, idxs in enumerate(idxss):
        embedding[i, idxs] = 1

    return embedding, dictionary
```

```
>>> strings = ["This is string one", "This is string two"]
... embedding, dictionary = embed(strings)

>>> dictionary
{'This': 0, 'is': 1, 'string': 2, 'one': 3, 'two': 4}

>>> embedding
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified your code a bit.

```
import numpy as np
def feature(strings):
    from collections import Counter
    vocabulary = global_vocab(strings)
    print(vocabulary)
    matrix=[]
    for string in strings:
        word_count_string=Counter(string.lower().split())
        string_count=[]
        for word in vocabulary:
            string_count.append(word_count_string[word])
        matrix.append(string_count)
    for row in matrix:
        print(row)
    matrix=np.array(matrix)
    print(matrix.shape)

# def word_count(book):
#     from collections import Counter
#     file = list(filter(lambda item: len(item)>2, book.lower().split()))
#     my_dict = Counter(file)
#     return my_dict
    
def global_vocab(strings):
    total_vocabulary = set()
    for string in strings:
        total_vocabulary.update(list(filter(lambda item: len(item)>2, string.lower().split())))
    return sorted(list(total_vocabulary))
    # return list(total_vocabulary)
    
feature(["This is string one", "This is string two"])
```

Output:

```
['one', 'string', 'this', 'two']                                                                                        
[1, 1, 1, 0]                                                                                                            
[0, 1, 1, 1]                                                                                                            
(2, 4)
```

Explanation:

global_vocab returns a list of unique words in all strings, this is saved into a variable called vocabulary and then printed to the screen, so that one can verify the output till here.

Now, we iterate over all strings in `strings` and for each string, we do the following:

1. get the list of frequency of words in this string and store it into
   `word_count_string` variable. We use `Counter` method from collections which returns a dictionary with keys as unique words in our string and values as frequency of this unique word.
2. At this point, we know, how many times each unique word of this string occurs in this string. Now we want the frequency of all words in vocabulary in this string.
3. We initialise an array names `string_count` which would store our required frequency of words.
4. Now we go over all the words in `vocabulary` and for each word append its count to `string_count`. We use the `word_count_string` dictionary to get the count of this word in this string. Remember `word_count_string` has already been calculated using Counter.
5. At last, we append `string_count` to `matrix` as a new row.

**Edit:**
Converted 2d list matrix to NumPy array, so that now you can do `matrix.shape`
One more thing, I also made the `global_vocab` to return a sorted list this time.

Comment: I am getting the error "'list' object has no attribute 'shape'" do you have any idea why this would happen?

Comment: The matrix in feature function in my code is a 2d list and lists do have any attribute called shape. You might be doing matrix.shape but here matrix is a 2d list and not a numpy array. You can easily convert it to numpy array using matrix = np.array(matrix) at the end of feature function. I am incorporating this change in my code. If you feel the code is as per your requirement, please upvote the answer.